# Tree traversal and serialization

Tags: data-structures, traversal, binary-search-tree

I am trying to get straight in my head how tree traversals can be used to uniquely identify a tree, and the crux of it seems to be whether the tree is a vanilla Binary Tree (BT), or if it also has the stricter stipulation of being a Binary Search Tree (BST). This [article](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/programming06/lecture12-21sep2006.txt) seems to indicate that for BT's, a single inorder, preorder and postorder traversal will not uniquely identify a tree (uniquely means structure and values of keys in this context). Here is a quick summary of the article:

**BTs**
1. We can uniquely reconstruct a BT with preorder + inorder and postorder + inorder.
  2. We can also use preorder + postorder if we also stipulate that the traversals keeps track of the null children of a node.

(an open question (for me) is if the above is still true if the BT can have non-unique elements)

**BSTs**
3. We cannot use inorder for a unique id. We need inorder + preorder, or inorder + postorder.

Now, (finally) my question is, can we use just pre-order or just post-order to uniquely identify a BST? I think that we can, since this question and
[answer](http://www.leetcode.com/2010/09/saving-binary-search-tree-to-file.html)
seems to say yes, we can use preorder, but any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what's being asked here.  *Any* binary tree, whether it's ordered or not, can be serialized by writing out a sequence of operations needed to reconstruct the tree.  Imagine a simple stack machine with just two instructions:

- Push an empty tree (or `NULL` pointer if you like) onto the stack
- Allocate a new internal node *N*, stuff a value into *N*, pop the top two trees off the stack and make them *N*'s left and right children, and finally push *N* onto the stack.

*Any* binary tree can be serialized as a "program" for such a machine.
The serialization algorithm uses a postorder traversal.

Comment: You don't visit empty nodes in those traversals though. So you cannot put placeholders like *NULL* in their places

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can use preorder only to identify a tree. This is possible because only in preorder traversal does the id-of-current-node comes before the ids of children. So you can read the traversal output root-to-leaves.

You can check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order to confirm

So you can consider a preorder traversal as a list of insertions into a tree. Because the tree insertion into BST is deterministic, when you insert a list of values into an empty tree, you always get the same tree.